# Registered Component click event in Aframe Version 0.8.2 and master isn't working

Tags: javascript, aframe

I was using this exact code in the previous version of Aframe 0.8.0 And the clicking was working normally.
However, when I tried using the 0.8.2 or the master version it showed no signs of clicking and without showing any errors

This is my registered component which I would like to detect clicks on the entities it is attached to

```
 AFRAME.registerComponent('change-color-on-hover', { 
    init: function () {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;  // <a-box>
        var defaultColor = el.getAttribute('material').color;
        /**
         * Attach 'click' event
         */
        el.addEventListener('click', function () {
          alert('clicked');
        });
     }});
```

The Element where I want to detect the click (I am setting its position later and they it's appearing where they should be)

```
  <a-image position="" src="#blue_target_rendered" height="30" width="40" depth="1" shadow event-set__click="_event: click; color:black" change-color-on-hover look-at="[camera]"  id="hotspot-{{$hotspot->id}}" data-link-to="{{$hotspot->link_to}}" data-link-from="{{$hotspot->link_from}}">
```

Comment: on 0.8.2 both 'click' and 'event-set' events are working properly, fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dm6Lk40g/5/). How is your cursor set ?

Comment: Weird becauses i didnt change any code from the working one on previous version : This is my camera + cursor                 <a-entity id="cameraParent"  position="0 0 0" >
        <a-entity id="cam" camera="zoom:1;"  look-controls collider-check position="0 0 0" >
          <a-entity cursor=" rayOrigin: mouse"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0; radiusOuter: 0"
            material="color: black; shader: flat"></a-entity>
      
          <a-entity raycaster="showLine:false; far: 1000" line="color:orange; opacity:1" ></a-entity>
        </a-entity>
      </a-entity>

Comment: I think i've overreacted a bit with the issue, check out my updated anwser :D
also commented on the [issue](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3878).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a setup like this:

```
<a-entity id="cameraParent" position="0 0 0" > 
   <a-entity id="cam" camera="zoom:1;" look-controls collider-check position="0 0 0" > 
      <a-entity cursor=" rayOrigin: mouse" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0; radiusOuter: 0" material="color: black; shader: flat"></a-entity> 
      <a-entity raycaster="showLine: true; far: 1000"></a-entity>
   </a-entity> 
</a-entity>
```

The `line` component created by the `raycaster` is interfering with the rays emitted by the `cursor = rayOrigin: mouse`. In other words, you're clicking on the element with the `line` on each click.

If you reposition the `raycaster` a bit:

```
<a-entity position="0 -0.1 0" raycaster="showLine:true; far: 1000"></a-entity>
```

The mouse cursor should be working fine.

Comment: Although i understand and agree with the suggested logic something very weird is happening after i implement the position change of the ray caster: if i put show line =true it catches intersections and disables clicking. if i put show line=false or  it does vise versa but i cant see to make the two work